# Jquery Dialog opening multiple times when contains textfield, textareas etc

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

For some reason when I open a dialog that contains input types it opens multiple Dialogs.

Here is my code:

```
    var addTagsDialog = $("<p>This is just a test tag</p> <br /><input type='text' />");

    addTagsDialog.dialog({
      buttons: {
        "Update": function () {
          console.log('Update Func Run');
        }
      },
      Cancel  : function () {
        addTagsDialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
      }
    });
```

## Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jrrxxbdg/

If I take out:

```
  <br /><input type='text' />
```

Then it only opens up one dialog modal.

I am using these versions:

- jquery 1.9.1
- jquery-ui-1.9.2

Can anyone see why this is the case?

I read on another questions that it is possibly because I am not destroying the modals after using them however each time I have used a modal I had added

```
dialog('destroy').remove();
```

and this does not explain how it is replicating in JSFiddle.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap everything into a DIV. When you create the elements that way, you're making a jQuery collection of 4 separate elements (`<p>`, `textElement`, `<br>`, `<input>`). Then it's creating a dialog for each of them.

Use:

```
var addTagsDialog("<div><p>This is just a test tag</p> <br /><input type='text' /></div>");
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that.